# How do I create an app to mimic the data on a website?

Tags: android, ios

Is it possible to create a mobile app for both Andriod and iOS which will display the same data as on a website written in HTML CSS and js?

The site only displays information but this info is used regularly by users. I have been asked if it's possible to create an app that the same info would be available on? Ideally, any changes made to the website would be reflected in the app without having to change the code for the app as well.

edit - The page on the app will still need functionality i.e being able to open modals when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed your site in a native app using a WebView. Nowadays you have several technologies as React native and Flutter that could help publishing your site as a multiplatform app.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into react native.